# Changing graphics in one point (itemize)

Tags: beamer, graphics, itemize

I'm struggling with the following thing:

I have an itemized list. I want to stop on one point (the 2nd) and show a graphic on the right of the list. Then, I want to stay inside the same point and replace the graphic with the other one.

```
\begin{frame}{The frame}
    The list:
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item Item 1;
        \visible<1>{\mbox{}\hfill\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{graphic1.jpeg}}}
        \item item 2: the one I want to explore futher;
        \visible<2>{\mbox{}\hfill\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{graphic2.png}}}
        \visible<3>{\mbox{}\hfill\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{graphic3.png}}}
        \visible<4>{\mbox{}\hfill\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{graphic4.png}}}
        \pause
        \pause
        \pause
        \item item 3;
        \item item 4.
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

I'm not really sure about the "pauses", but it's not the main issue. Graphic 3 is appearing under the text on the left, while Graphic 4 is not visible at all.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this:

[image: beamer slides]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{The frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
            The list:
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1;
                \item<2-> item 2: the one I want to explore futher;
                \item<5-> item 3;
                \item<6-> item 4.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
%            \only<1>{
                \begin{figure}
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
                \end{figure}
%            }
            \begin{figure}
                \only<2>{
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
                }
                \only<3>{
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
                }
                \only<4->{
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
                }
            \end{figure}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!